# How to import poorly named libraries?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

## Background

I am using a library called `baguettebox.js`

You can see it [here](https://github.com/feimosi/baguetteBox.js)

## Problem

When I import this into my project like

```
import * as BaguetteBox from 'baguettebox.js';
```

I get a warning flagged inside my IDE PhpStorm

> Cannot resolve file 'baguettebox.js'

This is because the folder & package.json are called baguettebox.js.

The Package is actually found and works in my application, I just want a good way to handle this error.

[image]

Comment: What module loader/bundler are you using? Webpack? Which version? Where are you getting this error? The IDE? The build log?

Comment: Simply rename your folders.

Comment: Error in the IDE

Comment: @Justinas not viable, these are installed with npm. Other developers will have the original name

Comment: If it's found and it works, doesn't that suggest that PHPStorm is showing an incorrect warning?

Comment: @robertklep yes I agree, I suppose it is an incorrect warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's the IDE issue. Please follow [WEB-25805](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25805) for updates